# Removing missing values from data frame and REORDERING it

Tags: r, dataframe

What I want to achieve is the following:
1) I have a data frame in which there are some rows with missing values. I want to remove them.
2) But at the same time, I want to reorder the rows of the data frame with respect to a certain vector element in it.

The code I have is:

```
x <- c(0,0,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.02,0.08,0.12,0.02,0.22,0.02,0.23,0.02,0.15) 
y <- c(0,0.03,0.01,0.13,0.08,0.12,0,0,0.02,0.2,0.01,0.17,0.04,0.11,0,0.08)
z <- x/y
```

I created a data frame with these as elements:

```
data <- data.frame(x,y,z)

data
     x    y         z
1  0.00 0.00       NaN
2  0.00 0.03 0.0000000
3  0.02 0.01 2.0000000
4  0.03 0.13 0.2307692
5  0.02 0.08 0.2500000
6  0.03 0.12 0.2500000
7  0.02 0.00       Inf
8  0.02 0.00       Inf
9  0.08 0.02 4.0000000
10 0.12 0.20 0.6000000
11 0.02 0.01 2.0000000
12 0.22 0.17 1.2941176
13 0.02 0.04 0.5000000
14 0.23 0.11 2.0909091
15 0.02 0.00       Inf
16 0.15 0.08 1.8750000
```

I want to remove Inf and NaN. I did it with the following code:

```
data = data[!(data$z %in% c(Inf, NaN, NA)),]

data
      x    y         z
2  0.00 0.03 0.0000000
3  0.02 0.01 2.0000000
4  0.03 0.13 0.2307692
5  0.02 0.08 0.2500000
6  0.03 0.12 0.2500000
9  0.08 0.02 4.0000000
10 0.12 0.20 0.6000000
11 0.02 0.01 2.0000000
12 0.22 0.17 1.2941176
13 0.02 0.04 0.5000000
14 0.23 0.11 2.0909091
16 0.15 0.08 1.8750000
```

Now I reorder these rows with respect to z (increasing order). I did it with the following code:

```
data = data[order(data$z),]
```

But I get the following output:

```
data
        x    y         z
10   0.12 0.20 0.6000000
11   0.02 0.01 2.0000000
NA     NA   NA        NA
12   0.22 0.17 1.2941176
NA.1   NA   NA        NA
4    0.03 0.13 0.2307692
14   0.23 0.11 2.0909091
NA.2   NA   NA        NA
16   0.15 0.08 1.8750000
13   0.02 0.04 0.5000000
NA.3   NA   NA        NA
6    0.03 0.12 0.2500000
9    0.08 0.02 4.0000000
5    0.02 0.08 0.2500000
3    0.02 0.01 2.0000000
2    0.00 0.03 0.0000000
```

Not only did it not reorder correctly, the missing values I deleted (4 of them) somehow revived.

Why is this happening?

I don't run into this sort of problem if I order it first, and then remove the Inf and NaN. Could someone shed some light on why the deleted elements comeback when I try to reorder them after deleting them?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I think you called your order on earlier dataframe which had NA/InF. code is working properly. Try naming the df where you removed something else and then do order on it.

Comment: I can't replicate this (everything matches up to the second-to-last step). What do get from `find("order")` ... ?

Comment: above code runs perfect...try again..

Comment: I used data[order(z),] instead of data[order(data$z),] ... And it works well... Ah, this is embarrassing. I'll delete the post soon. Thanks everyone..